# How do I create a CAST in Informix to cast an LVARCHAR to TEXT?

Tags: casting, types, informix

What built-in routine can I make use of to cast data of type `LVARCHAR` to data of type `TEXT`?

The larger context: I have a table with a column that has been defined as `LVARCHAR(4096)`.  Now a developer wishes to change the data type of this column to `TEXT`.  Ideally this would be done with:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY bar TEXT;
```

...but in such a case the following error is puked to the screen:

```
ALTER TABLE can not modify column (bar) type. Need a cast from the current type to the new type.
```

I have read up on the `CREATE CAST` construction, but I cannot begin to think what on earth the proper conversion function would look like.  Without a function, Informix will not allow the `CREATE CAST` to work.  That is, if I do, simply:

```
CREATE CAST (LVARCHAR AS TEXT)
```

...Informix tells me that a cast function is required (which makes sense).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware, Informix developers: if you inadvertently run into a problem like this, *there is no way to get out of it using SQL or DDL alone*.  Let me repeat that.

If you have a `VARCHAR` or an `LVARCHAR` column that you need to migrate to be a `TEXT` column, and if you cannot afford to lose data in that column, *there is no way to do this in SQL or DDL*.

Instead, you must write a program that does the conversion for you inside the database driver, in memory.  In my case, I used [JDBC mutable result sets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_UPDATABLE) and copied the column to a new column, letting the JDBC driver perform the conversion, then dropped the old column, and renamed the new column back to the old column.  This general pattern is the only way to migrate existing character data into a `TEXT` column.

Comment: I really don't miss Informix at all. Thanks for the reminder! :)

Answer (score 2):

@Storm: Which version of IDS/ODBC are you using? AFAIK, IDS 9 or 10 can't do that without using specific embedded C in server (See boulder site), but in no way you can do that directly through SQL. Blob related functions or so.

Othe way is by using UNLOAD / LOAD.

In my scenario, we have lots of problems: no admin rights to enterprise server, as we are service providers, we only can use database, but cannot modify structure. We cannot modify TEXT fields only by launching queries.